# Where and how to set form for nested resources in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an `Idea` model, which has one `Chat`, and of course, this chat has messages.
Based on the following routes, **I want to create a form in the chat page to post messages.**

```
# Chat belongs_to :idea, and Chat has_many :chat_messages
# I wan't to post messages to /idea/:id/chat/chat_messages
    resources :ideas do
        resource :chat, only: :show do
            resources :chat_messages, only: :create
        end
      end
```

For now, my form is in `app/views/chats/show.html.erb` and looks like that :

```
  # @chat and @chat_message are defined in Chat controller but I put them here so you can see them
  @chat = Chat.where(idea_id: params[:idea_id]).first
  @chat_message = ChatMessage.new(chat: @chat)

<%= form_for [@chat.idea, @chat, @chat_message] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
    <%= f.submit "Message" %>
<% end %>
```

The form generates the following html (I have removed the inputs and some content which was not relevant) :

```
<form action="/ideas/1/chat/chat_messages.1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
</form>
```

**Why is there `.1` in my form action ?** (it causes error). How should it be ? i need it to access `/ideas/1/chat/chat_messages`

Comment: Try this `form_for [:idea, @chat, @chat_message]`

Comment: Perfect thanks, it works !! :) But why ? Apart from that, do routes look fine and restfull ? I'm a beginner at nested resources

Comment: Glad it helps! And routes look okay to me. It completely depends on the requirement. But from the rails documentation `Resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep.` If you are using latest Rails version we have better options on nested resources. I believe that you are good at reading docs :)

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know about that. Thank you, and feel free to make your comment an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

`form_for [:idea, @chat, @chat_message]`